# Brackets around multiple outputs in Python function

Tags: python, matlab

In matlab, if we have a function that returns multiple variables, we do something like

```
[output1, output2] = some_func()
```

In Python, you can simply do

```
output1, output2 = some_func()
```

Or you could do

```
[output1, output2] = some_func()
```

Or

```
(output1, output2) = some_func()
```

The last 2 makes some temporary list and tuple, respectively, but it is not assigned to anything, and you can access the 2 output variables identical to the case without `[]` or `()`. Is there anything actually functionally *advantageous* to using the last 2 syntax besides somewhat looking a little more elegant?

Comment: I'm new to Python and I was asking if there is anything actually functionally different with using `[]` and `()` when you have multiple output variables. Maybe I should have asked if there's anything advantageous to using `[]` and `()`. I'll update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference I can think of between

```
[output1, output2] = some_func()
```

and

```
(output1, output2) = some_func()
```

is that the latter's memory footprint *should* be smaller (but I'm sure that this is an [implementation detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777719/what-is-the-definition-of-an-implementation-detail)) since tuples take less memory than lists with the same number of elements, mainly because tuples are immutable (so the interpreter should not need to worry about adding or removing [ie re-allocating memory] elements).

```
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof([1, 2]))
print(sys.getsizeof((1, 2)))
print(sys.getsizeof([1, 2, 3, 4]))
print(sys.getsizeof((1, 2, 3, 4)))
print(sys.getsizeof(list(range(1000))))
print(sys.getsizeof(tuple(range(1000))))

#  80
#  64
#  96
#  80 
#  9112
#  8048
```

The generated bytecode is exactly the same for all 3 examples:

```
from dis import dis


def foo(): return 1, 2


def a():
    output1, output2 = foo()


def b():
    [output1, output2] = foo()


def c():
    (output1, output2) = foo()

dis(a)
print('-----------------------------------------------------')
dis(b)
print('-----------------------------------------------------')
dis(c)
```

outputs

```
 81           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (output1)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (output2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
-----------------------------------------------------
 85           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (output1)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (output2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
-----------------------------------------------------
 89           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (output1)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (output2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: @PranavChaudhary you can see that just above the bytecode

Comment: Okay, Thanks. That was helpful.